# How to install missing function package of Octave in Mac?

Tags: macos, octave

I try to install the symbolic package for the Octave in the Mac, https://octave.sourceforge.io/symbolic/index.html, which path should be set?

More fundamental problem is that I follow the commands suggested by https://octave.sourceforge.io/ to install the symbolic package described as above, but the "pkg install" is always shown "pkg: command not found" in the command line. How to deal with it?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and resolved it by using "pkg -forge install symbolic", which installs from the forge central repository.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you entered the `pgk install` command in the osx shell. It has to be issued in octave. Start octave first, then run `pgk install symbolic` in octave´s command line.
To see installed package list user `pkg list` command.